# How to run Visual Studio 2008 and WAMP server on same local machine running WIndows7?

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, php, wamp, visual-studio-2008

I'm having a machine running on Windows 7. First I installed WAMP server on my local machine. It was working fine. Then I installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2008. From that time the WAMP server is not working at all. Means the **"W"** symbol of WAMP server gets **Green** but nothing is working like if I print **`http://localhost/abc`** or **`http://localhost/phpmyadmin`**. The page loader keeps on revolving and revolving and ultimately after long time error message comes. I gone into the details of this issue. Then I found Apache server is not running. Also I checked port 80 status. But nothing is worked for me till now. Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the apache port number in `httpd.conf` configuration file of Apache server. (`c:\wamp\Apache2\conf\httpd.conf`)

Change the line `Listen 80` to `Listen 8081`. Restart your Apache server. You can check the logfiles of apache and/or VS (SQL Server on port 80) to see which apps have conflict, probably a conflicting port 80. I see there were other question about this same problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/479469/the-localhost-of-visual-studio-doesnt-show-up-when-i-have-wamp-server-installed

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6872576/how-to-open-port-80-for-apache-previously-occupied-by-visual-studios-servers

Comment: gooodaaaaaaaaaaaa